# What does DORMANT status in sqo results mean?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When typing "sqo" in the Skyrim SE (Windows Steam) command console, I get a list of active quests and their status. Quite a few have the status DORMANT. What does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DORMANT means you have not triggered it.  It is in contrast to ACTIVE and COMPLETED.

For example, in the quest [Innocence Lost](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Innocence_Lost), the one previous to joining the Dark Brotherhood, you are tasked to kill Grelod the Kind.

This quest stays DORMANT, until you talk to Aventus Aretino in Solitude to start the quest, which is the typical way of starting this quest.  Alternatively, you can just go up to Grelod and kill her.  Both of this trigger the quest and you should see it become ACTIVE.

Comment: Side note: if you're trying to avoid triggering Blood on the Ice in Windhelm (as this quest temporarily endangers NPCs by setting a murderer on the town), offing Grelod in Riften just for being horrible is a good way to get into the DB early. 

Also, DORMANT status exists because all of the quests still exist in the world whether you've obtained them or not, and this status is sometimes actively checked to prevent things like having said murderer go on the spree before you get to Windhelm.